# is there a way to solve reduction of order differential equations when you get a complex number without having to do long derivative substitution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

so our goal for this problem is to find y2

so far for all these problems I have been using the formula

[image]

With this new problem listen above we get a complex root, and my teacher instructed us that we could use either this really long route to find y2 by taking a lot of substitutions and derivatives, but he also suggest there was a way shorter way to solve these as well. he never gave us the shorter route for when you get complex roots.

from my own attempts I found this,

ex: your roots are $1 \pm 4i $ you could make it $ e^xcos(4x) + e^xsin(4x) $

am I anywhere in the right direction?

Comment: I think you mean $e^xcos(4x) + ie^xsin(4x)$. However, in many applications it is much easier to use complex powers of $e$ rather than a trig form.

Comment: @S.Dolan do you have a recommended way to solve this without using the long derivative substitution way?

Comment: What is your function $P$?

Comment: so were trying to find y2, this case the answer of problem 3. that I posted up there is 'sin4x', but I want to know how to reach that consistently with other problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general solution of your differential equation is $A\cos 4x+B\sin 4x$.

If you are asking for a general method of solution of $y''+by'+c=0$ then the simplest method is to solve the quadratic equation $m^2+bm+c=0$.

If this has complex roots $u+iv$ and $u-iv$, then the general solution is $$e^{ux}(A\cos vx+B\sin vx).$$

Comment: ok thank you, in the specific problem I posted you get complex roots, but if you use that formula I posted you get the right answer still, does that mean I can just use that formula for every single problem?

Comment: You can use the method I gave above for all second order differential equations with constant coefficients.